# how to decide if customer is a dimension

Tags: data-warehouse

I am creating a data warehouse (data mart) for a project-based (labor-centric) organization.  (That is, they sell labor-based "projects"; they don't sell physical products.)  They are interested in project- and customer-related dimension info.  I need to make a design decision about a certain dimension.  Should I make this dimension be "Project" (with customer info as attributes on this dimensions)?  Or, should I make two separate dimensions -- one for project and another for customer?  What are some questions to ask (or things to think about) to help me make this decision?

Answer (score 0):

If the customer and the project represent axisis for analysis you can proceed with the following design :

[image]

The customer and the project can be Slowly Changing dimensions where you decide a type from the following :

```
SCD Type    Summary
Type 1      Overwrite the changes
Type 2      History will be added as a new row.
```

The fact table can handle measures like the cost, the number of working days...

Comment: That does not answer my question.  Suppose I have 2+ dimensions (e.g., project and customer).  One option is to place them in separate dimension tables.  Another option is to place them in the same dimension table.  What determines the solution?  Is it, say, coupling?  That is, if there are no project attributes that are a function of the customer (and vice versa), then they should live in separate dimension tables?

Comment: What is the cardinality between customer and project and what are the attributes for each ?

Comment: There is a 1:many relationship from Customer to Project.  That is, one customer can have many projects.  A project can only have 1 customer.  Right now, there are about 20 project attributes and 10 customer attributes.  I expect the quantity of attributes to change, but the proportion should stay the same.